# x(t)=asin(ωt):y(t)=acos(ωt);z(t)=bt i have to find the velocity, the acceleration and then their absolute values

Tags: absolute-value

x(t)=asin(ωt):y(t)=acos(ωt);z(t)=bt 
i have to find the velocity, the acceleration and then their absolute values. I did not understand how I can calculate the absolute value.

Comment: You work here with 3-dimensional vectors. So synonyms for absolute value are magnitude or modulus.

Comment: I have found Vx(t)=awcos(wt), Vy(t)=-awsin(wt) and Vz(t)=b, so the absolute value of the velocity? how can I calculate since the parameter is in the angle?

Answer (score 0):

By definition of velocity:
$$\nu = (a\omega\cos(\omega t), -a\omega\sin(\omega t), b) \Longrightarrow |\nu| = \sqrt{a^2\omega^2+b^2}$$
By definition of acceleration:
$$\alpha = (-a\omega^2\sin(\omega t), -a\omega^2\cos(\omega t), 0) \Longrightarrow |\alpha| = |a|\omega^2$$

Comment: oh thank you! if I have to find the absolute value of the velocity=(4t,-6t,8t) it is square root of (4^2+(-6)^2+8^2) ? or not?  and then for the acceleration, the absolute value will be 0?

Comment: Yes, since it goes on line produced by $(2,-3,4)$, at constant velocity $\sqrt{116}$, obviously its acceleration is $0$ for sure.

Comment: so the absolute value of velocity will be root of 116 and the absolute value of acceleration will be just 0?

Comment: Yes, that is what i was said.

Comment: okay, thank you so much